# How to call a function by clicking on left arrow fron keyboard?

Tags: angular

I want to call a function by pressing the left arrow from the keyboard.
what I did is:

```
<div (keydown.ArrowLeft)="makeItFalse();move('meko',1)"></div>
```

but the problem is that I want to call the function by pressing the left arrow any time while the file is executed.
can you help me?

Comment: Register keyboard listenerm, analyze pressed key, act accordingly.

Comment: can you please write here the code?

Answer (score 2):

Just register a listener, filter and process accordingly.

**Example:**

```js
@HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])
keyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if(event.keyCode==37){
        alert("yep, left arrow");
    }
    console.log(event.keyCode);
}
```

This will print key code and will invoke alert on left arrow.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-examples-z8n5an